# Why my custom @objc function in swift have a strikethrough in the autofill?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently learning swift 5.2 and I found a problem when I try to use #selector and @objc function.

I created a @objc function and I call it in the #selector, but the function has a strikethrough in the autofill. Just like some other functions that is deprecated. It doesn't really affect anything, the app work just fine. But I really want to know why the strikethrough appears.

Someone says that is because the function recommend a return value. And I tried to return something, like a Bool, in the @objc function. And the strikethrough is gone, but it still affect nothing, no matter what the function returns.

This really confused me. Is there any one who can tell me why? Thanks!

[image]

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```
let refreshControl_A = UIRefreshControl()
let refreshControl_B = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    refreshControl_A.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh_A(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl_B.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh_B(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func refresh_A(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    print("Have strikethrough!")
}

@objc func refresh_B(sender: UIRefreshControl) -> Bool {
    print("No strikethrough!")
    return true
}
```

The refresh_A function has the strikethrough in the autofill.
But the refresh_B function doesn't have the strikethrough in the autofill.
The only difference between these two functions is the return type, one is Viod, and the other is Bool. Both functions work fine.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure, I have update my question with my example. Thank you.

Comment: No they don’t both work fine. An action selector cannot return a value.

Comment: @matt I think it can return the value. The value won't be used though.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, well, I admit I did something sly with the word "cannot". But it isn't going to return any value _to the system_ when the system calls in because the user tapped, so that's why Xcode disqualifies it as an action selector: it doesn't match the required signature.

Comment: When I use your exact code, my Xcode doesn't show any strikethroughs.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, unfortunately the code in the screen shot is obscured by the autocompletion popup, so we can't reproduce. But it looks to me like the code is inside a define-and-call instance property initializer - that might have something to do with it. Nothing like what the OP showed in the actual code...

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you for your help. The code in the screen shot is very similar to my minimal reproducible example. I have watched many recent tutorials( which made in 2020), but none of them will show up a strikethrough. Which makes me even more puzzled. I think I should try my code in xcode 10 to see if the strikethrough appears.

Comment: @matt Yes, the function doesn't reall return anything to the system. But adding a return type to the function do make the strikethrough disappear. My xcode version is 11.5, and my Swift version is 5.2.4.

Comment: So the problem is solved.